# Complex number and Quadratic quesiton - Given roots of equation, find variable $q$.

Tags: complex-numbers

$$x^2 + 4x + 20 = 0$$
$$x=-2 \pm 4i$$

Roots of Quadtratic $z^2 + (4+i+qi)z + 20 = 0$ - Roots are $w$ and $w*$

(a) When $q$ is real, explain why it must be $-1$

**Attempts:**

Roots are conjugates therefore the coefficient must be real - and to get rid of the imaginary parts $q$ must be $-1$?

(b) Where $w=p+2i$ and $p$ is real, find the values of $q$.

**Attempt:**

Subbed $p+2i$ into equation to give $p=2$, where it is real. Substitute $2+2i$ into the equation again and get $q=3$, and $q=-8$? Very sure this is not correct - Should be a complex number?

Thank you.

Comment: i think your first argument is ok

Comment: if for b) the same equation valid?

Comment: This is all information given - I would assume so - I think possible roots of equations is required.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for part **(b)**: given the root $p+2i\,$, the other root is $\,\cfrac{20}{p+2i}\,$ by Vieta's relations.

Then, again by Vieta's relations for the sum of the roots:

$$
p+2i + \cfrac{20}{p+2i} = -(4+i+qi)
$$

The latter gives $q$ in terms of $p$. The solution is not unique, for each $p \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a complex $q$ given by the equation above such that $p+2i$ is a root.